# Yii2 breadcrumb not showing

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

Here's the code to show breadcrumb on my view

```
<div class="container">
    <?= Breadcrumbs::widget([
        'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
    ]) ?>
    <?= $content ?>
</div>
```

But when I change div class to "container-fluid" the breadcrumb not showing anymore and I really don't know why? I'm new to Yii2.

Please help me with this.

Sorry for my bad English. Thank you.

Comment: Does the rendered html code contains the breadcrumb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with padding. The `.container` class (inside `.wrap`) has `padding: 70px 15px 20px;` what gives enough padding top for the breadcrumbs to be shown below the top navbar .The `container-fluid` class has no padding and the breadcrumbs lie behind the top navbar. Add `padding-top: 70px` to your `.container-fluid` class and you will see your breadcrumbs again.